# Why are these java code representation/translation of UML incorrect?

Tags: java, uml, class-diagram

I have this slide from my professor:

[image]

I don't understand why public class H and public class I are incorrect?

Is it because due to the lack of navigability shown (no arrows), you assume it's either 0 or greater than 0, so you MUST include them as an attribute field?

Comment: They are not incorrect, unless your professor and/or your book says that *unspecified navigability* should be navigable anyway.

Comment: It’s not clear to me either, if the association had a name attached to it it might have give a clue of the relationship between H and I but now I don’t get it.

Answer (score 0):

`H` and `I` have an association per UML but not per code.

p. 111 of UML 2.5:

> `<multiplicity-range>` is the multiplicity range of the Property. If this term is omitted, it implies a multiplicity of 1 (exactly one). (See MultiplicityElement – sub clause 7.5.)

So you must implement it as single reference on both side. Without there will not be an association and that would be wrong.

Comment: So you are saying it is the same as F & G?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Two-way navigability can use no arrows or one at each end.

Comment: Ok but I guess my problem here is how we can say something conclusive about this navigability and express it in code, which is what is expected here as I understand it. To me this just say there is a link between H and I but not what that link is.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson See Fig. 11.29 on p 203 of UML 2.5

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Just read those pages around the referenced picture. It's quite clear that an association without adornment needs exactly one object reference on both ends.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Funny enough, I started this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59320067/non-navigability-definition